# UK Visa Refused, Applied again waiting

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, application-status

I had applied for a UK visitor visa and it got refused saying there were not enough funds and also they thought I would not be able to take care of my wife and child. I checked the mistakes and reapplied with more precise information and proof of funds. 
The first time I had applied I got the reply in 10 days however this time it has already been 14 days and there is no reply. Only I got an email on 16 August, 2016 informing that it is reached British High Commission, Chennai. 
Could anyone help me how much time will this take? 
In the email they mention with 15 working days.
August 18 was a holiday as it was Raksha Bandhan and also September 5. I wanted to know how much time could it take as i applied for Visitor Visa for 6 months and do i need to count 15 working from the day I got the email or from the next date ? Any help could be great. 
My brother is in UK as he is a citizen so attached sponsorship letter too.

Comment: The estimate you got cannot be subjected to rigorous day counting methods and you cannot lodge an enquiry until their full 90 days has elapsed anyway. See below for the official links. You are having post-submission anxiety and I have updated the tags on your question.

Answer (score 3):

The 15 days are just a guideline based on statistics.

As you can see on the [Home Office's page for Visa processing times](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/chennai-india/visits-visas/family-visit-6-months-or-less), 99% of applications in July 2016 were processed within 15 days, and 100% within 30 days.

Slightly longer processing times, especially when a previous visa was refused or there are public holidays involved are to be expected.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds normal to me. If you had documents missing first time then they don't need to examine closely, they can just refuse it quickly right away. If everything looks to be  in place though then they have to take time to actually examine your documents.

Don't worry about it unless they're a few days beyond what they promised, then you can ask them and they should give you an answer.

I don't think anyone can really give a better answer here unless they work in the relevant office. Who knows what might be going on to cause them to have extra work lately.

Update:

The British Consulate in Chennai for contact details:
https://www.gov.uk/government/world/organisations/british-deputy-high-commissioner-chennai

And some data for Chennai's processing times here:
https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/chennai-india/visits-visas/all

99% are done within 15 days though 1% may take up to 30 days.

Comment: Is there a site where one can query the average processing time for the Chennai Visa Section?